# Apache2 Server How To Make A Python File Executable but not readable by People Viewing The Site

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, apache2

I am creating a web server with Apache2 on a Raspberry Pi. There is one Problem. I want a python file to be executed by PHP like:

```
$result = shell_exec("python someFile.py");
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
```

But if I want that file to run I have to make it readable. and then people can view the code and see sensitive information about the site.
is there any way I can make the file be executed but not readable by any people.
They would be able to see it if they went to the file like so:

```
PI_IP_ADDRESS/pyFile.py
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think this is better asked on serverfault.com. stackoverflow is for programming issues but this is about how to configure and run your web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the python file outside of the scope of apache. For example place the python file in your home directory, and then just call the file with the full directory in the php file.
`$result = shell_exec("python ~/someFile.py");`

Comment: Thank you that worked! I put in the www directory and used shell_exec("python ../file.py")